In my CurriculumVitae class, the WorkExperience list does not appear
I am making a small application in Spring Boot for a curriculum. This is my CurriculumVitae class where I am encountering the issue of getting empty lists in the JSON response from the API.
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "curriculum_vitae")
public class CurriculumVitae {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "curriculumVitae", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<WorkExperience> workExperiences;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "curriculumVitae", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<LevelEducation> levelEducations;

}

In my Curriculum class, I created a WorkExperience list. When I test my API in Postman, the JSON response returns a list of empty objects.
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Jean Dupont",
        "lastName": "Dupont",
        "workExperiences": [],
        "levelEducations": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Jean Dupont",
        "lastName": "Dupont",
        "workExperiences": [],
        "levelEducations": []
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Jean Dupont",
        "lastName": "Dupont",
        "workExperiences": [],
        "levelEducations": []
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Jean Dupont",
        "lastName": "Dupont",
        "workExperiences": [],
        "levelEducations": []
    }
] 

Does anyone have an idea of what the problem might be? So far, I haven't found the solution. I'm posting part of the code from my classes.
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "work_experience")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("curriculumVitae")
public class WorkExperience {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String company;

    private String position;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date startDate;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date endDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "curriculum_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private CurriculumVitae curriculumVitae;

}

My DTOs for both classes.
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CurriculumVitaeDTO implements Serializable {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8732529708250756609L;

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String lastName;

    private List<WorkExperience> workExperiences;

    private List<LevelEducationDTO> levelEducations;

    }

@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class WorkExperienceDTO {

    private Long id;

    private String company;

    private String position;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date startDate;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date endDate;
}


My mappers, I am using MapStruct for the mapping.
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CurriculumVitaeMapper {

    CurriculumVitaeMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CurriculumVitaeMapper.class);


    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "id", target = "id"),
            @Mapping(source = "workExperiences", target = "workExperiences"),
            @Mapping(source = "levelEducations", target = "levelEducations")
    })
    CurriculumVitaeDTO toDto(CurriculumVitae curriculumVitae);

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "id", target = "id"),
            @Mapping(source = "workExperiences", target = "workExperiences"),
            @Mapping(source = "levelEducations", target = "levelEducations")
    })
    CurriculumVitae toEntityCurriculumVitae(CurriculumVitaeDTO curriculumVitae);
}


@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface WorkExperienceMapper {

    WorkExperienceMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(WorkExperienceMapper.class);

    @Mapping(source = "id", target = "id")
    WorkExperienceDTO toWorkExperienceDTO(WorkExperience workExperience);

    @Mapping(source = "id", target = "id")
    WorkExperience toEntityWorkExperience(WorkExperienceDTO workExperienceDTO);
}

my service the classes
@Service
public class CurriculumVitaeServiceImpl implements CurriculumVitaeServiceInter {

    private final CurriculumVitaeRepository curriculumVitaeRepository;

    private final CurriculumVitaeMapper curriculumVitaeMapper;

    public CurriculumVitaeServiceImpl(CurriculumVitaeRepository curriculumVitaeRepository, CurriculumVitaeMapper curriculumVitaeMapper) {
        this.curriculumVitaeRepository = curriculumVitaeRepository;
        this.curriculumVitaeMapper = curriculumVitaeMapper;
    }


    @Override
    public List<CurriculumVitaeDTO> getAllCurriculumVitaes() {
        return curriculumVitaeRepository.findAll()
                .stream()
                .map(curriculumVitaeMapper::toDto)
                .toList();
    }

    @Override
    public CurriculumVitaeDTO createCurriculumVitae(CurriculumVitaeDTO curriculumVitaeDTO) {

        if (curriculumVitaeDTO.getName() == null || curriculumVitaeDTO.getName().isEmpty()) {
            throw new BadRequestException("The name of Curriculum Vitae  is mandatory");
        }

        var newCurriculumVitae = curriculumVitaeMapper.toEntityCurriculumVitae(curriculumVitaeDTO);
        newCurriculumVitae = curriculumVitaeRepository.save(newCurriculumVitae);

        return curriculumVitaeMapper.toDto(newCurriculumVitae);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<CurriculumVitaeDTO> getCurriculumVitaeById(Long id) {
        if (!curriculumVitaeRepository.existsById(id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Curriculum Vitae with id " + id + " doesn't exist");
        }
        return curriculumVitaeRepository.findById(id).map(curriculumVitaeMapper::toDto);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteCurriculumVitae(Long id) {

        if (!curriculumVitaeRepository.existsById(id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Curriculum Vitae with id " + id + " not found");
        }
        curriculumVitaeRepository.deleteById(id);
    }


@Service
public class WorkExperienceServiceImpl implements WorkExperienceServiceInter {


    private final WorkExperienceRepository workExperienceRepository;

    private final WorkExperienceMapper workExperienceMapper;

    public WorkExperienceServiceImpl(WorkExperienceRepository workExperienceRepository, WorkExperienceMapper workExperienceMapper) {
        this.workExperienceRepository = workExperienceRepository;
        this.workExperienceMapper = workExperienceMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public List<WorkExperienceDTO> getAllWorkExperience() {
        return workExperienceRepository.findAll()
                .stream()
                .map(workExperienceMapper::toWorkExperienceDTO)
                .toList();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<WorkExperienceDTO> getWorkExperienceById(Long id) {
        if (!workExperienceRepository.existsById(id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Work experience with id " + id + " doesn't exist");
        }
        return workExperienceRepository.findById(id).map(workExperienceMapper::toWorkExperienceDTO);
    }

    @Override
    public WorkExperienceDTO createWorkExperience(WorkExperienceDTO workExperienceDTO) {
        WorkExperience newExperienceDTO = workExperienceMapper.toEntityWorkExperience(workExperienceDTO);
        newExperienceDTO = workExperienceRepository.save(newExperienceDTO);

        if (workExperienceDTO.getCompany().isEmpty()) {
            throw new BadRequestException(" The name of Company is mandatory ");
        }

        return workExperienceMapper.toWorkExperienceDTO(newExperienceDTO);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteWorkExperience(Long id) {
        if (!workExperienceRepository.existsById(id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Work experience with id " + id + " not found");
        }
        workExperienceRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}


My controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class CurriculumVitaeController {

    private final CurriculumVitaeServiceInter curriculumVitaeServiceInter;

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CurriculumVitaeController.class);


    public CurriculumVitaeController(CurriculumVitaeServiceInter curriculumVitaeServiceInter) {
        this.curriculumVitaeServiceInter = curriculumVitaeServiceInter;
    }


    @GetMapping(value = "/curriculumVitaes", produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_GRAPHQL_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<CurriculumVitaeDTO>> getAllCurriculumVitaes() {

        List<CurriculumVitaeDTO> curriculumVitaeDTOList = curriculumVitaeServiceInter.getAllCurriculumVitaes();

        if (curriculumVitaeDTOList != null && curriculumVitaeDTOList.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        }
        logger.info("Find CurriculumVitae service finished");
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(curriculumVitaeDTOList);

    }


    @PostMapping(value = "/curriculumVitae", produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<CurriculumVitaeDTO> createCurriculum(@Valid @RequestBody CurriculumVitaeDTO curriculumVitaeDTO) {
        if (curriculumVitaeDTO.getName() == null || curriculumVitaeDTO.getName().trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new BusinessException("Curriculum Vitae is required", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        CurriculumVitaeDTO newCurriculumDTO = curriculumVitaeServiceInter.createCurriculumVitae(curriculumVitaeDTO);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(newCurriculumDTO);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/curriculumVitae/{id}", produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<CurriculumVitaeDTO>> getCurriculumVitae(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Optional<CurriculumVitaeDTO> newCurriculumVitae = curriculumVitaeServiceInter.getCurriculumVitaeById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(newCurriculumVitae);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/curriculumVitae/{id}", produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteCurriculumVitae(@PathVariable Long id) {
        curriculumVitaeServiceInter.deleteCurriculumVitae(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Curriculum Vitae is deleted");

    }

    @PutMapping(value = "/curriculumVitae/update", produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<CurriculumVitaeDTO> updateCurriculumVitae(@Valid @RequestBody CurriculumVitaeDTO curriculumVitaeDTO) {
        if (curriculumVitaeDTO.getId() == null) {
            throw new BusinessException("Curriculum Vitae is required", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        CurriculumVitaeDTO updateCurriculumVitae = curriculumVitaeServiceInter.createCurriculumVitae(curriculumVitaeDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(updateCurriculumVitae);
    }

}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class WorkExperienceController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WorkExperienceController.class);

    private final WorkExperienceServiceInter workExperienceServiceInter;

    public WorkExperienceController(WorkExperienceServiceInter workExperienceServiceInter) {
        this.workExperienceServiceInter = workExperienceServiceInter;
    }


    @GetMapping(value = "/workExperiences", produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<WorkExperienceDTO>> getAllWorkExperience() {
        List<WorkExperienceDTO> workExperienceDTOList = workExperienceServiceInter.getAllWorkExperience();

        if (workExperienceDTOList.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(workExperienceDTOList);
    }


    @PostMapping(value = "/workExperience", produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<WorkExperienceDTO> createWorkExperience(@RequestBody WorkExperienceDTO workExperienceDTO) {
        if (workExperienceDTO.getCompany() == null || workExperienceDTO.getCompany().trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new BadRequestException("Company name cannot be empty");
        }

        WorkExperienceDTO newWorkExperience = workExperienceServiceInter.createWorkExperience(workExperienceDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(newWorkExperience);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/workExperience/{id}", produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<WorkExperienceDTO>> getWorkExperienceById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Optional<WorkExperienceDTO> workExperienceDTO = workExperienceServiceInter.getWorkExperienceById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(workExperienceDTO);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/workExperience/{id}", produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteWorkExperience(@PathVariable Long id) {
        workExperienceServiceInter.deleteWorkExperience(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Work Experience deleted");
    }

    @PutMapping(value = "/update")
    public ResponseEntity<WorkExperienceDTO> updateWorkExperience(@Valid @RequestBody WorkExperienceDTO workExperienceDTO) {
        if (workExperienceDTO.getId() == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(null);
        }

        var updateWorkExperienceDTO = workExperienceServiceInter.createWorkExperience(workExperienceDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(updateWorkExperienceDTO);
    }

}



thank you for your hepls
I am making a small application in Spring Boot for a curriculum. This is my CurriculumVitae class where I am encountering the issue of getting empty lists in the JSON response from the API

You aren't using the WorkExperienceDTO in your CurriculumVitaeDTO , and you should specify the mappers used on the CurriculumVitaeMapper using the uses keyword in the @Mapper annotation. Also you sholud remove the INSTANCE stuff as you are using Spring as your model not the regular way of obtaining your mappers.

Hello, thank you for your messages. However, I don't understand your proposal.
